# how do I use leaflet heatmap with time dimension plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, json, leaflet, heatmap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TimeDimension</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src='javascripts/heatmap.js'></script>
    <script src='javascripts/leaflet-heatmap.js'></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/styles/default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-rc.2/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.fullscreen/1.4.2/Control.FullScreen.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/leaflet.timedimension.control.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" />
    <style>
        a.leaflet-control-timecontrol.timecontrol-date {
            width: 120px;
            padding-left: 50px !important;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #map {height: 700px; weight: 100px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-rc.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.fullscreen/1.4.2/Control.FullScreen.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/ptv-logistics/Leaflet.NonTiledLayer/master/NonTiledLayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/ptv-logistics/Leaflet.NonTiledLayer/master/NonTiledLayer.WMS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nezasa/iso8601-js-period/master/iso8601.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/heatmap.js/2.0.2/heatmap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/pa7/heatmap.js/develop/plugins/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.stamen.com/js/tile.stamen.js?v1.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/felixge/node-dateformat/master/lib/dateformat.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/timeDim/leaflet.timedimension.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/timeDim/leaflet.timedimension.util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/timeDim/leaflet.timedimension.layer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/timeDim/leaflet.timedimension.layer.wms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/timeDim/leaflet.timedimension.layer.geojson.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/timeDim/leaflet.timedimension.player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/timeDim/leaflet.timedimension.control.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

    Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
        return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
    };

    // Attibution: SODA API requests based on this example: https://github.com/chriswhong/soda-leaflet

    L.TimeDimension.Layer.SODAHeatMap = L.TimeDimension.Layer.extend({

        initialize: function(options) {
            var heatmapCfg = {
                radius: 20,
                maxOpacity: 1,
                scaleRadius: false,
                useLocalExtrema: false,
                latField: 'lat',
                lngField: 'lng',
                valueField: 'count/15'
            };
            heatmapCfg = $.extend({}, heatmapCfg, options.heatmatOptions || {});
            var layer = new HeatmapOverlay(heatmapCfg);
            L.TimeDimension.Layer.prototype.initialize.call(this, layer, options);
            this._currentLoadedTime = 0;
            this._currentTimeData = {
                max: this.options.heatmapMax || 10,
                data: []
            };
            this._baseURL = this.options.baseURL || null;
            this._period = this.options.period || "P1M";
        },

        onAdd: function(map) {
            L.TimeDimension.Layer.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
            map.addLayer(this._baseLayer);
            if (this._timeDimension) {
                this._getDataForTime(this._timeDimension.getCurrentTime());
            }
        },

        _onNewTimeLoading: function(ev) {
            this._getDataForTime(ev.time);
            return;
        },

        isReady: function(time) {
            return (this._currentLoadedTime == time);
        },

        _update: function() {
            this._baseLayer.setData(this._currentTimeData);
            return true;
        },

        _getDataForTime: function(time) {
            if (!this._baseURL || !this._map) {
                return;
            }
            var url = this._constructQuery(time);
            $.getJSON(url, (function(data) {
                delete this._currentTimeData.data;
                this._currentTimeData.data = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var marker = data[i];
                    if (marker.location) {
                        this._currentTimeData.data.push({
                            lat: marker.location.latitude,
                            lng: marker.location.longitude,
                            count: 1
                        });
                    }
                }
                this._currentLoadedTime = time;
                if (this._timeDimension && time == this._timeDimension.getCurrentTime() && !this._timeDimension.isLoading()) {
                    this._update();
                }
                this.fire('timeload', {
                    time: time
                });
            }).bind(this));
        },

        _constructQuery: function(time) {
            var bbox = this._map.getBounds();
            var sodaQueryBox = [bbox._northEast.lat, bbox._southWest.lng, bbox._southWest.lat, bbox._northEast.lng];

            var startDate = new Date(time);
            var endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
            L.TimeDimension.Util.addTimeDuration(endDate, this._period, false);

            var where = "&$where=created_date > '" +
                    startDate.format('yyyy-mm-dd') +
                    "' AND created_date < '" +
                    endDate.format('yyyy-mm-dd') +
                    "' AND within_box(location," +
                    sodaQueryBox +
                    ")&$order=created_date desc";

            var url = this._baseURL + where;
            return url;
        }

    });

    L.timeDimension.layer.sodaHeatMap = function(options) {
        return new L.TimeDimension.Layer.SODAHeatMap(options);
    };



    var currentTime = new Date();
    currentTime.setUTCDate(1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var map = L.map('map', {
        zoom: 12,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        timeDimension: true,
        timeDimensionOptions: {
            timeInterval: "2010-01-01/" + currentTime.toISOString(),
            period: "P1M",
            currentTime: currentTime
        },
        center: [40.74, -73.9],
    });

    var layer = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png");
    map.addLayer(layer);

    //baselayer---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    var testSODALayer = L.timeDimension.layer.sodaHeatMap({
        baseURL: 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/erm2-nwe9.json?$select=location,closed_date,complaint_type,street_name,created_date,status,unique_key,agency_name,due_date,descriptor,location_type,agency,incident_address&complaint_type=Noise - Commercial',
    });
    testSODALayer.addTo(map);
    map.attributionControl.addAttribution('<a href="https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Social-Services/311-Service-Requests-from-2010-to-Present/erm2-nwe9">NYC OpenData</a>');

    L.Control.TimeDimensionCustom = L.Control.TimeDimension.extend({
        _getDisplayDateFormat: function(date){
            return date.format("mmmm yyyy");
        }
    });

    //heatmapLayer------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    var timeDimensionControl = new L.Control.TimeDimensionCustom({
        playerOptions: {
            buffer: 1,
            minBufferReady: -1
        }
    });
    map.addControl(this.timeDimensionControl);

</script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/highlight.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <a href="http://localhost:2999" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" role="button">Back</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example12.html

I found this example and successfully run in my localhost,

but how do I change the data to my own json file?

my code now is almost the same as above example.

I tried $getJson and several methods to read my json data, but all of them doesnt work.

dont know which part of code should I change

Comment: Please post your complete Code.

Comment: I just want to make one page, so I put the code altogether in ejs file don't want to make project too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify _constructQuery method, that receives a time value and constructs the URL for that particular time.

Check also this issue at github, that discusses how to load a different JSON for each time: https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/issues/19

Comment: I just found this issue yesterday haha thanks for answering my question, I m going to try this